# input file in ipad only let me choose pictures using ionic

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

i'm trying to attach documents to an item using an input file, works well in android i can choose a pdf file, but on the ipad only images can be selected.
is this a normal behaviour on ipad ?

```
    <div ng-show="type.mode!=3">
  <h3>Pièces jointes</h3>
  <div class="uploader-buttons-container">
    <!-- PDF uploader -->
    <div class="custom-uploader">
        <span>Ajouter <strong>PDF</strong></span>
        <input type="file" class="upload" accept="application/pdf" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().pdf(this)" />
    </div>
    <!-- Image uploader -->
    <div class="custom-uploader">
        <span>Ajouter<i class="mini-symbol icon ion-image"></i></span>
        <input type="file" class="upload" capture="camera" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photo(this)" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
accept="image/*"
```

in input. Remove it and will be fine. It's not related to iPad.